# Optimizing query when trying to find latest record in multiple tables for specific column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, union-all

Problem: Find the most recent record based on (created) column for each (linked_id) column in multiple tables, the results should include (user_id, MAX(created), linked_id). The query must also be able to be used with a WHERE clause to find a single record based on the (linked_id).

There is actually several tables in question but here is 3 tables so you can get the idea of the structure (there is several other columns in each table that have been omitted since they are not to be returned).

```
CREATE TABLE em._logs_adjustments
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  user_id integer,
  created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  linked_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT _logs_adjustments_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE em._logs_assets
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  user_id integer,
  created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  linked_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT _logs_assets_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
CREATE TABLE em._logs_condition_assessments
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  user_id integer,
  created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  linked_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT _logs_condition_assessments_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

The query i'm currently using with a small hack to get around the need for user_id in the GROUP BY clause, if possible array_agg should be removed.

```
SELECT MAX(MaxDate), linked_id, (array_agg(user_id ORDER BY MaxDate DESC))[1] AS user_id FROM (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(created) as MaxDate, asset_id AS linked_id FROM _logs_assets
    GROUP BY asset_id, user_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id, MAX(created) as MaxDate, linked_id FROM _logs_adjustments
    GROUP BY linked_id, user_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id, MAX(created) as MaxDate, linked_id FROM _logs_condition_assessments
    GROUP BY linked_id, user_id
    ) as subQuery
    GROUP BY linked_id
    ORDER BY linked_id DESC
```

I receive the desired results but don't believe it is the *right* way to be doing this, especially when array_agg is being used and shouldn't and some tables can have upwards of 1.5+ million records making the query take upwards of 10-15+ seconds to run. Any help/steering in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for ORDER BY (see above). Note that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first

```
select distinct on (linked_id) created, linked_id, user_id
from (
    select user_id, created, asset_id as linked_id
    from _logs_assets
    union all
    select user_id, created, linked_id
    from _logs_adjustments
    union all
    select user_id, created, linked_id
    from _logs_condition_assessments
) s
order by linked_id desc, created desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Clo, but looking to have the query return the max(created) for each linked_id.

Comment: @Spade That is exactly what it does.

Comment: My fault it does work as expected (thank you!), but execution time does not change much it is on par/the same as the query being used now.

Comment: @Spade Is there an index on `linked_id` on all tables?